# select sql statement... error with from clause

Tags: sql

Table 1: **Students**

```
Name   Class PK
John   Mike  1
Andrei Tom   2
```

Table 2: **Grades**

```
Disciplne Grade PK_student
math       2    1
math      10    1
math       8    2
math       5    2
```

What it's the correct statement to delete rows in table 2 grades by PK from students. My point it's to delete a studente from databse and his grades. Thanks

i try to delete in c# grades for a student. I read name and second name, and it should remove his grades from  table

OleDbCommand comanda1 = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM GRADES WHERE PK_student=SELECT PK FROM Students WHERE Name=@p0 AND Class=@p1 ; ", conex);

```
comanda1.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("p0", v[0]));
omanda1.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("p1", v[1]));
```

it gives me an error in FROM clause.

Comment: Do you want to delete both student and his grades from both tables acccording to given student id?

Comment: The delete statement with join on another table can be different depending on your dbms. By the way, this question has few dozens of answers on SO...

Comment: your question title indicates you are receiving an error with your attempted query? you should include both (the query and the error you are receiving) into your question, people like to see what you've done yourself around here ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the data rfom table 2 by table 1 then you can use following query:

```
DELETE FROM GRADES WHERE PK_student IN (SELECT PK FROM STUDENTS);
```

Hope this is the desired query you want to achieve.